# Завершить все процессы пользователя на Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash

Как это сделать?

Определить имена пользователей, с правами которых запущенны процессы. Завершить выполнение процессов, запущенных с правами некоторого пользователя.

Comment: 1) `man ps` (например, `ps aux`) 2) вытащить оттуда  PID нужных процессов и послать им `TERM` (как - варианты уже разные...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Пример, завершаем (хе-хе) все процессы пользователя `root`:

```
$ ps au | grep -e '^root' | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -TERM
```

Ergo, в этом случае копать в сторону `man ps`, `man grep`, `man awk`, `man xargs`.

Comment: как работает команда xargs?

Comment: берез со стандартного ввода строчку и запускает команду kill -TERM $@ передав эту строчку как аргументы. Так для каждой

Answer (score 5):

В копилку,

Есть шикарные команды **pgrep** и **pkill** из пакета [procps-ng](https://gitlab.com/procps-ng/procps)

```
~# pkill -u USER
```

завершит все процессы пользователя USER

```
~# pgrep -u USER
```

покажет все PID пользователя USER

Пример PinkTux можно сократить до:

```
~# ps aux | awk '/^USER/ {print $2}' | xargs kill -9
```